# Redirect Loop while rewriting URL for a video file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a video file whose url is modified by .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^videos/([0-9]+)/.*$ cms/support/get.file.php?file_id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now when i load the file 
`http://web01.agmsdallas.com/videos/966/`

I end up with redirect loop and the page fails to load. I have checked by .htaccess rule with others and  this appears good. The rule works on a different server. Can any one help what could be wrong. Is there some apache directive which is disabled which is causing this error.

Comment: Rule looks fine, something else is causing the redirect loop

Comment: If you have more rules in your .htaccess then paste complete .htaccess here.

Comment: We further zeroed down the issue. It seems some thing else is rewriting the URL. I created /videos/966/index.html, went to http://web01.agmsdallas.com/videos/966/
and the flv started downloading! This shows the htaccess is working. There is some redirect kicking in when the folder is missing and apache is getting 404.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the issue been the welcome.conf file of apache which has

```
<LocationMatch "^/+$">
    Options -Indexes
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/noindex.html
</LocationMatch>
```

Once we commented that out, the redirection works just fine.